# Can C program be used without main function?

Tags: c

From a Fortran Code, I intend to run a C code (to read a file) and fetch the read information.
The main program is the Fortran code, which uses a function written in C to do the processing.
In this C code, is it necessary to run a main function?

Comment: You mean, to use a function from a library written in C from Fortran? (I haven't really touched Fortran, but I have no reason to think you wouldn't be able to.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling C Code from FORTRAN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354182/calling-c-code-from-fortran)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Fortran only calls the C function, then the C code does not need a `main()` function.

The `main()` function of C is the program entry point. The system loads the .exe, transfers control to the startup code, which address is mentioned in the .exe file (the startup code is called `crt`, C run-time start-up). The run-time startup does initialization and then transfers control to the user code. The user code entry point is `main()`.

Since Fortran is the main program, no C run-time start-up is needed and so no `main()` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need a `main` in your C code. The linker will use the `main` from the FORTRAN code, or rather, the FORTRAN equivalent of `main`, when linking your C functions to the FORTRAN program.